# Append throwing an exception

Tags: c#

I was trying to create a fixed lenght(left aligned) batch file with the below code.

when i use Append it's throwing exception "is a method but used like a type".

```
            string batFilePath = @"c:\mockforbat.bat";
        if (!File.Exists(batFilePath))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(batFilePath))
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }

        //write
        using (StreamWriter sw = new File.AppendText(batFilePath))
        {
            string a = String.Format("{0,-24}{1,-5}{2,5}", "CostCenter", "CostObject", "ActivityType");
            sw.WriteLine(@a);

        }
        Process process = Process.Start(batFilePath);
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Please some one correct me what i did wrong here ?

Comment: BTW, that's not an exception, but a compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the `new` operator from this line

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new File.AppendText(batFilePath))
```

It should read

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(batFilePath))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string batFilePath = @"c:\mockforbat.bat";
using(var fs = new FileStream(batFilePath , FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        string a = String.Format("{0,-24}{1,-5}{2,5}", "CostCenter", "CostObject", "ActivityType");
        sw.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```